# Kotlin sealed classes - why doesn't compiler check for all subtypes?

Tags: kotlin, sealed-class

When using [sealed classes](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html), the compiler only checks for subtypes in the same file.

One of the big selling points of sealed classes is the exhaustive checks when using a `when` expression. So why isn't this implemented?

In 1 file I have:

```
class C : B()
```

In another file I have:

```
sealed class A

open class B : A()

fun switch(input: A) =
    when(input) {
        is B -> Unit
//        is C -> Unit - I expect a compiler error since this is a subtype and it's commented out
    }
```

Comment: The first case - `is B` covers all subclasses of B. There is no need to `C`. But you may have `is C` case before `B`, than it will make sense

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that C is a B so `is B` covers it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eugene Petrenko [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334380/kotlin-sealed-classes-why-doesnt-compiler-check-for-all-subtypes?noredirect=1#comment95486789_54334380), the `is B` case that is required by the compiler covers all subclasses of B.